# if cell modified data on col1 by appscript?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script

I want,

If B1 edited/Not empty, put TimeStamp on A1. here is my script-

```
  function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = s.getRange(r, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is not empty
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is, `getRange(r, 1)` which should be `getRange(r, -1)` as colB=0, colC=1 colA=-1
But putting -1 is not working. How to fix that??

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
if(r.getColumn() == 2){
    var prevCellValue = r.offset(0,-1).getValue;
    if(prevCellValue() !== ''){
        r.offset(0,-1).setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```